# Always chose first element in the list

Tags: r, list, vector, extract

Let's consider list:

```
x <- list(c(1), c(1,2), c(2,3,4))
```

This list has three elements - vectors on each position. I want to extract first element of those vectors:

**My primitive solution**

```
extract_vec <- c()
for (i in seq_len(length(x))) { 
  extract_vec[i] <- x[[i]][1]
}
```

Will do the job, however I wonder if loop has to be used for doing so. I tried something like `x[[1:3]][1]` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
lapply(x, '[', 1)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

sapply(x, '[', 1)
[1] 1 1 2
```

Comment: Now we're talking!